# save url parameter data to text file php

Tags: php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$myFile = "lidn.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $id;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

above code is working fine.

But I want to save each data on a new line.

Thanks.

Comment: instead of flag 'w' use 'a' and provide . '/n' or . PHP_EOL at end of fwrite!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `"\n"` like below:-

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$myFile = "lidn.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $id;
fwrite($fh, $stringData."\n");
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: @MayankS.Gupta  please check once with my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a newline character to the string you saving.

Like `$stringData = $id . "\n";` for example.

Comment: previous data is getting deleted and new data getting added . not working.

Comment: Did you put on same line as before using `$stringData`?  Just below the `fopen` line yes?  It should just be adding newline